# Does this proof sketch show that finding a SHA-1 preimage is NP-hard?

Tags: sha-1, complexity, preimage-resistance

Jutla & Patthak wrote "[Is SHA-1 conceptually sound?](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Is-SHA-1-conceptually-sound--Jutla-Patthak/0a268e13cb061b619bf62907bb2c51913cd1cf16/pdf)" back in 2005, in which they provide a proof sketch (Appendix A) to show that finding a preimage for SHA-1 is NP-hard.  Now, there are some issues with the proof sketch (as far as I can see).  It does not take into account the additional constraints introduced by linear message-expansion; and it does not handle the CHOICE function and is therefore applicable to rounds >20.  At a somewhat more pedantic level, the constructions look a bit artificial, but perhaps that's just aesthetics.

Nevertheless, it seems that if the proof sketch does hold true, then this provides a NP-hard model for two-thirds of SHA-1 preimage-finding, which seems like it should be a big deal.  The paper has never been published in conference proceedings or journals, nor is it cited by the most significant SHA-1 preimage work in recent years (i.e., Knellwolf & Khovratovich ; Rechberger; and Aoki & Sasaki).  I assume that there's something more important that's wrong with the proof as a whole, but I'm not sure what it could be.

So my questions is: what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> they provide a proof sketch (Appendix A) to show that finding a preimage for SHA-1 is NP-hard

No, they don't.  The definition of a problem being NP-hard is "if you have an Oracle that can solve instances of this problem in polynomial time, you can solve any problem in NP in polynomial time"; as we can quickly find SHA-1 preimages using a huge lookup table, we can easily see that finding SHA-1 preimages is not NP-hard (unless P=NP, in which case every problem is NP-hard)

What they do (at best) is show is a class of problems that are jointly NP-hard (of which finding SHA-1 preimages may be an instance).  However, that doesn't tell us anything about the concrete difficulty of SHA-1; NP-hard problems can have easy instances (trivial example: travelling salesman problem over every city in the world; is there a circuit that's at most 1 kilometer total distance?  Even though the traveling salesman problem is NP-hard, this is a trivially solved instance)

Comment: If you have a 10-input 3SAT problem and the time to test $2^{10}$ input variations, can't you also make a huge lookup table to "solve" that 3SAT problem?  But that doesn't mean that 3SAT is not NP-complete.  I'm not sure how having a LUT changes the difficulty of the problem.

Comment: @Rhyme: indeed, 3SAT problems restricted to 10 bits inputs is also not NP-complete; you need to allow the problem to scale to arbitrary size before NP-complete/NP-hard becomes a possibility.  You can have a LUT to solve the problem for 10 bits of inputs; you can't (or, at least, it's not obvious how) to apply a LUT to quickly solve an arbitrary sized input (and, remember, you're not allowed to precompute different LUTs as the input grows)

Comment: Aren't they basically saying: "There is this problem which is (probably?) NP hard. If we could solve it, we could also construct collisions/preimages for SHA-1." I.e. finding SHA-1 images can be much easier *in other ways*.

Comment: @poncho, is this not also the case for SHA-1? Assuming only a single block of input, precomputing all $2^{447}$ possible solutions is not possible, and a lookup table becomes impractical.  Since neither 3SAT nor SHA-1 can be scaled up using a LUT, I'm not sure what the difference is ...

Comment: @otus: essentially, that's what they are saying.  Now, this is true of any NP-complete problem; however the problem they give is "close" to the SHA-1 preimage problem (unlike, say traveling salesman), and it's not obviously generic (unlike, say, SAT problem).

Comment: @Rhyme: actually, from a complexity theoretical view (and the terms "NP-hard" and "NP-complete" are complexity theoretical terms), there's no problem with precomputing $2^{447}$ solutions (or $2^{160}$ preimages for the $2^{160}$ possible outputs); yes, that's impractical, but complexity theory doesn't care about that.  In contrast, with 3SAT, you have a potentially unbounded number of possible solutions (as the problem size grows without limit), and so it's not only infeasible, but impossible to have a finite table that lists the solutions.